# C#: Copy multiply files in folder and keep the folder-structure

Tags: c#, file, copy, directory

I want to copy all .txt files which exist in "Main-Folder" and subfolders to "Main-Folder-Copy".

```
Main-Folder
├── Folder 1
│   ├── file0.jpg
│   ├── file1.ini
│   ├── file2.dll
│   └── file3.txt
└── Folder 2
    ├── file4.dll
    ├── file5.txt
    └── Folder 3
        ├── file6.txt
        ├── file7.jpg
        ├── file8.dll
        └── file9.txt
```

When copying to an other place I want to keep the folder structure like this:

```
Main-Folder-Copy
├── Folder 1
│   └── file3.txt
└── Folder 2
    ├── file5.txt
    └── Folder 3
        ├── file6.txt
        └── file9.txt
```

My idea was to copy the whole "Main-Folder" to a temp folder and delete all the unnecessary files. When facing bigger folders this could become a problem because the whole folder has to get copied in first place. Are there any better solutions?

I tried working with `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Answer (score 2):

The below code was taken from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories), it should be easy to implement into any program and pretty self explanatory. If you know what the unnecessary files are you might be able to filter them when copying

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DirectoryCopyExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Copy from the current directory, include subdirectories.
        DirectoryCopy(".", @".\temp", true);
    }

    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, very similar to previous MSDN answer:

```
public static void Copy(string sourceDirectoryName, string targetDirectoryName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDirectoryName);

    DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryName);
    DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectoryName);

    CopyWork(source, target);
}

private static void CopyWork(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in source.GetDirectories())
        CopyWork(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));

    foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name));
}
```

They never put in a `System.IO.Directory.Copy()` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This example below might help you:

```
string dirA = @"Main-Folder\";
string dirB = @"Main-Folder-Copy\";

string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirA);

foreach (string s in files) {
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).equals(".txt")) {
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName), true);
    }
}
```